# How to extract text from an EditText view - Android

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

So I guess It was a simple as using a getText() to retrieve the information :)

Here is how it ended:

```
public void getToast(View v) {
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userText);
    String toastText = et.getText().toString();
    if (toastText == "" || toastText == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This is a nice toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    }
    else {
    Toast.makeText(this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I have created an *EditText* View on the main layout file. This is referenced to with the *userText* identifier. As it is an *EditText* field, the user is able to modify the text within it at any moment; what I am trying to accomplish is to retrieve the text the user has entered at the moment they tap on the button identified as *getToast*, and then display it as a Toast.

I am using the Resources class at the moment (my first guess?) to retrieve the String stored under *toastText* but this is useless, as it is extracting the text stored in the main.xml - which is empty, as I declared no "android:text" attribute for that view, instead I used an "android:hint" to tell the user to enter the text.

I had read about intents, but that kind of makes sense if I was to send the String to another activity, not within the same one. I had thought of it as a simple task, but it is consuming more time that I had hope :P

BTW:

The *getToast* method is defined as an "android:OnClickMethod" for a button created on the XML. It will work with any other string of text.

Any ideas?

```
package com.testlabs.one;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class initialui extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
}

public void getToast(View v) {
    Resources myResources = getResources();
    String toastText = myResources.getString(R.string.toast); 
    if (toastText == "" || toastText == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This is a nice toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    }
    else {
    Toast.makeText(this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply call the function `getText()` on the TextView.

Example:

```
public void getToast( View v )
{
    String toastText = ( (EditText)v ).getText();
    if ( toastText.length() == 0 ) {
        toastText = getResources().getString( R.string.toast );
    }
    Toast.makeText( this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}
```

This code will display a toast with the text in your EditText when it is available and the default text in the `toast` resource when nothing was entered.

Comment: Thanks man, I feel like such a douchebag :(
That did work though, and I got the Toast to display the text on the View :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send a string from one activity to the other via an Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key","stringValue");
startActivity(intent);
```

then in your other activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key","defaultstring");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userText);
String toastText = et.getText().toString();
```

Should be this:

```
String toastText  = findViewById(R.id.userText).toString();
```

If not, I would like to know why you needed to use the intermediate phase and not cast it straight to a java String object